# cocos2d Mac Shutdown and Startup at runtime

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

We are building a content editor that brings up a "cocos Player" in an `NSWindow` for test purposes.  The user can test some content and then close the window.

So I need to be able to shutdown cocos and re-start within the same app.

Everything is working if I use the `CC_MAC_USE_DISPLAY_LINK_THREAD` threading model.  I had to make a fix in `CCDirectorMac` to get this working.  In `CCDirectorMac | stopAnimation` I had to set the `_runningThread` to `nil` since it is not set to nil by the `#if` and `#elif` when using `CC_MAC_USE_DISPLAY_LINK_THREAD`.

Anyway so now I am able to "end" a director and then re-start it later with no issues.

My question though is this:  If I am building an AppKit editor with occasional use of cocos2D whould my threading model really be `CC_MAC_USE_MAIN_THREAD` as is suggested in the documentation?

When I do use `CC_MAC_USE_MAIN_THREAD` I get a *HANG* in in `stopAnimation` on the line:

`CVDisplayLinkStop(displayLink);`

I think the main thread would be fine and would avoid threading issues for our tool.  Performance is not a concern.  I can't find any sample code that shuts down and restarts cocos2d in an `NSWindow` ... so my assumption here is that I am in untested waters (or little tested waters).

My steps to shutdown/restart are:

1. Call `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end]`
2. This calls `stopAnimation`
3. Then re-initialize cocos2d the same way I did originally

Any advice on threading models for a Mac desktop app ... and why `CVDisplayLinkStop` hangs would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior in my app. If I switch to CC_MAC_USE_MAIN_THREAD (which solves some weird problems I was getting) it hangs when I try to quit the app (which calls [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end]). Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out after reading this post and its answers on the Apple mailing list: http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2006/Oct/msg00056.html

When using `CC_MAC_USE_MAIN_THREAD`, the display link thread uses `performSelector:onThread:waitUntilDone:` to run `drawScene:` on the main thread. It passes `YES` for the `waitUntilDone:` parameter, so the display link thread *blocks* until the main thread can process the `drawScene:` call.

Here's the relevant fragment of the cocos2d code. `MyDisplayLinkCallback` is called on the display link thread.

```
static CVReturn MyDisplayLinkCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp* now, const CVTimeStamp* outputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags* flagsOut, void* displayLinkContext)
{
    CVReturn result = [(CCDirectorDisplayLink*)displayLinkContext getFrameForTime:outputTime];
    return result;
}

- (CVReturn) getFrameForTime:(const CVTimeStamp*)outputTime
{
#if (CC_DIRECTOR_MAC_THREAD == CC_MAC_USE_DISPLAY_LINK_THREAD)
    ...
#else
    // Display link thread blocks here:
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawScene) onThread:_runningThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
#endif
    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}
```

The problem appears when the main thread tries to run `CVDisplayLinkStop()` which *blocks* until the display link callback in the display link thread finishes. Since the callback is at the same time waiting for the main thread to process its drawScene: call, both threads become **deadlocked**.

```
- (void) stopAnimation
{
    ...

    if( displayLink ) {
        // Main thread blocks here:
        CVDisplayLinkStop(displayLink);
    ...
}
```

So, now for my workaround. I added a line to run the main thread's runloop in order to force the `drawScene:` call to be executed, which unblocks the display link thread. That way, when you call `CVDisplayLinkStop()` you're safe. Here's my addition (CCDirectorMac.m line 473 in cocos2d 2.1 release):

```
- (void) stopAnimation
{
    ...

    if( displayLink ) {
#if (CC_DIRECTOR_MAC_THREAD != CC_MAC_USE_DISPLAY_LINK_THREAD)
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
#endif
        CVDisplayLinkStop(displayLink);
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure this is *the* right thing to do, there's probably a better way to deal with this, but this workaround is good enough for me at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had similar issue with custom OpenGLView, but only for Retina display. After replacing `waitUntilDone` from `YES` to `NO` application doesn't hang at start.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post, it helped me figure out how to solve the same deadlock, in a non-cocos2d app, by processing the display link callback on a separate thread, never on the main thread.

```
static CVReturn MyDisplayLinkCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp* now, const CVTimeStamp* outputTime,
                                      CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags* flagsOut, void *userInfo)
{
    static dispatch_queue_t sDisplayQueue;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sDisplayQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.app.displayLink", NULL);
    });

    dispatch_sync(sDisplayQueue, ^{
        <stuff>
    });
    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}
```